# SQL Server 2012 identity column JUMPS without restart

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am already aware that SQL Server jumps by a certain number whenever the server or service is restarted. But, in my issue SQL Server 2012 jumps by 1000 even when the service and server were not restarted. 
What could be the issue with this..?

In my case identity column are extremely important since it represents unique id which is getting used in various places and a gap in it is not expected.

Comment: Do you know that even a rollback can cause Identity jump. Read [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)

Comment: What is the problem with that? Identity values are meaningless. A value of 34654562 is just as good as a value of 8923 or 1000 or 2000

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017#remarks)

> The identity property on a column does not guarantee the following:
>
> - If a particular insert statement fails or if the insert statement is rolled back then the consumed identity values are lost and will not
>     be generated again. This can result in gaps when the subsequent
>     identity values are generated.

For the point

> But what if I don't want any gaps in the identity column. Is there any way so as to avoid this JUMP without affecting the performance of the server database? Also in my case identity column is important since it represents an id which is getting used everywhere and a gap in them is not expected.

The response is: you shouldn't use identities with business logics. Your best bet would be using sequences, although they also have the problem that won't be reset when rolled back. However you can reset them to the intial value before the transaction if the rollback happened with a few more statements.